# simple limit but I forget how to prove it

Tags: calculus

I have to calculate the following limit

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - x$$

it is in un undeterminated form.

I tried to rewrite it as follows:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - \sqrt{|x|^2}$$

but seems a dead road.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Try rationalizing the expression.  That is, multiply by $1=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+x}$ to get
$$
\frac{(x^2+2x+2)-x^2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+x}
$$
What can we do from there?

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Putting $y=-x,$
$$ \sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - x=\sqrt{y^2-2y+2} +y= \frac{(\sqrt{y^2-2y+2} +y)(\sqrt{y^2-2y+2} -y)}{(\sqrt{y^2-2y+2} -y)}$$
$$=\frac{y^2-2y+2-y^2}{\sqrt{y^2-2y+2} -y}=\frac{-2+\frac2y}{\sqrt{1-\frac2y+\frac2{y^2}}-1}$$

Comment: @GrahamHesketh, how about this one?

Comment: When $x\to-\infty$, $y\to+\infty$ and your last quantity goes to $+\infty$ (numerator goes to $-2$, denominator to $0^-$).

Answer (score 2):

Clearly
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - x=+\infty+\infty=+\infty$$ 
But 
\begin{gather*}\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - x="\infty-\infty"=\\
=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{(\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - x)(\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} + x)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} + x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{2x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} + x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{2+2/x}{\sqrt{1+2/x+2/x^2} + 1}=1
\end{gather*}

Comment: oops ))$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you meant $\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} + x$ (as $\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} - x \to +\infty$ when $x\to-\infty$):

Another option would be to use asymptotics and known Taylor expansions (at $0$): for $x\to-\infty$,
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2+2x+2} + x &= |x|\sqrt{1+\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{x^2}} - |x| \\
&= |x|\left( 1+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{x} + o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 1 \right) \\
&= \frac{|x|}{x} + o(1) \sim -1
\end{align*}
$$
so the limit is $-1$.